# How do i get the value from Relatedlist

Tags: apex, related-list

If I have a visualforce email template with relatedToType="customObject__c" can I get field values of a relatedlist of this customObject without using a controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. This is not possible without using custom controller. You need t make a component and pass the parent Id as attribute and then in component query the records and display them.

Here is a code sample for you

**Email template**

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Embedding Apex Code" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Opportunity">
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody>
        <p>As you requested, here's a list of all our Smith accounts:</p>
        <c:smithAccounts/>
        <p>Hope this helps with the {!relatedToType}.</p>
    </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Component

```
<apex:component controller="findSmithAccounts" access="global">
    <apex:dataTable value="{!SmithAccounts}" var="s_account">
        <apex:column>
            <apex:facet name="header">Account Name</apex:facet>
            {!s_account.Name}
        </apex:column>
    </apex:dataTable>
</apex:component>
```

Controller

```
public class findSmithAccounts {

    private final List<Account> accounts;

    public findSmithAccounts() {
        accounts = [select Name from Account where Name LIKE 'Smith_%'];
    }

    public List<Account> getSmithAccounts() {
        return accounts;
    }
}
```

[Using Custom Controllers within Visualforce Email Templates](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_email_templates_with_apex.htm)

Comment: You "can" actually do so, but with the obvious caveat that you cannot order the records in any way other than the default sort order for SOQL queries.

Comment: @sfdcfox I never thought we can use it here as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the related records of the object by using its relationship. However, you cannot choose the order without using a custom controller. They will be organized in whatever order the system decides to render them (usually by record Id).

Here's a trivial copy-paste example for you to to play with:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Account Contacts" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Account">
  <messaging:plainTextEmailBody >
These are your contacts:
    <apex:repeat value="{!relatedTo.Contacts}" var="contact">
{!contact.Name}
    </apex:repeat>
  </messaging:plainTextEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```